# Is there a way to watch the change of service`tasks in docker swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Anybody who knows Is there a way to watch the change of service`tasks in docker swarm mode?
Any some examples?

Answer (score 2):

First, list the services:

```
docker service ls
```

Then you can list the tasks running for a given service with:

```
docker service ps <service>
```

Example:

```
$ docker service ps redis
ID                         NAME      SERVICE IMAGE        LAST STATE          DESIRED STATE  NODE
0qihejybwf1x5vqi8lgzlgnpq  redis.1   redis   redis:3.0.6  Running 8 seconds   Running        manager1
bk658fpbex0d57cqcwoe3jthu  redis.2   redis   redis:3.0.6  Running 9 seconds   Running        worker2
5ls5s5fldaqg37s9pwayjecrf  redis.3   redis   redis:3.0.6  Running 9 seconds   Running        worker1
```

After a `docker service scale` you can see the new tasks being added or removed depending on the number desired.

You can also follow the **status change** (running/stopped, etc.) for tasks under the `LAST STATE` column.

All these informations about task status change are also available through the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/tasks).